# Tensorflow for 32bit Raspbian OS

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, debian, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to install tensorflow and keras in debian 11. After some research i used messed with pyenv and virtualenv installed keras. But whenever i use pip3 install tensorflow it shows "" ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow"". I found out that tensorflow does not work with 32bit python.So do i have to reinstall my debian as 64bit, because i am running it in raspberry pi 4 and realvnc does not support 64bit operating system.Any help to get over this will be appreciated ;)

Answer (score 0):

You hit a speed bump when trying to set up your new work environment. Because you need TensorFlow and Keras you have no alternative except to start from scratch, reinstall Raspbian (the 64-bit version ) and install either Remmina or TigerVNC instead of RealVNC.